# Unit Test function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have this code in my component. But I'm not sure if I'm unit testing it correctly

```
const UnderConstruction = () => (
  <div className="under-construction"
    style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}
  >
    <p>Under construction</p>
  </div>
);
```

Here's my unit testing code. But doesn't seem to work

```
it('Renders with a className equal to the variant', () => {
  const {
    container: { firstChild },
  } = render(
    <div
      className="under-construction"
      style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}
    >
      <p>Under construction</p>
    </div>,
  );
  expect(firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to test component `UnderContruction` you need to render it explicitly:

```
const {
    container,
  } = render(<UnderConstruction />);
```

And then make checks against it:

```
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

PS To me, it's rather waste of time to test static component without any logic inside.